# Как извлечь usb устройство с помощью WinApi?

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

Как используя средства WinApi безопасно извлечь телефон или компьютерную мышь из usb порта?
Уже пробовал использовать CM_Request_Eject(), удалось извлечь флешку, но не телефон.

Comment: Может телефон просто не требует "безопасного извлечения"?